# R scatterplot conditioning on "name pattern"

Tags: r, scatter-plot, lattice

)
I'm trying to produce three scatterplots for which the groups depend on the name of the column matrix so that the first plot contains all the values on the columnnames starting with A, the 2nd starting with B and the 3rd starting with C. 
I found a method how to extract the values of the data matrix based on the starting letter (assigned to the variable "condition"). Unfortunately I don't know how to extract solely the variable names so that the scatterplot is getting produced. The minimal example is listed below:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

data <- matrix(data= 1:9, nrow = 5, ncol = 9) #produces my matrix

colnames(data) <- c("A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3", "C1", "C2", "C3")
p <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3) #my probabilities
#data contains now my final matrix
mean <- colMeans(data) #taking the mean of the columns
xyplot(mean ~ p  , type = "l", lwd=2, xlab = "error rate", ylab = "error magnitude", groups = grep("A", colnames(data))) #scatterplot via lattice-package
```

can anybody help me?

Comment: sorry I updated my code. 
what I'm trying to achieve is three plots - each one on the column names "A", "B" and "C" but it's not working...

Comment: yes that's exactly it :-)
thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

```
library(tidyverse)
cbind.data.frame(M=mean,P=p) %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  mutate(rowname=gsub("[[:digit:]]","", rowname)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(M,P)) + 
      geom_point() + 
      facet_grid(~rowname)
```